# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal - how to prevent multiple modals opening

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've implemented the modal directive, and set the `$modal.open` option backdrop to `false`. However, now I can trigger multiple modals to open. Is there a way to prevent the trigger button from firing once one modal is open?

```
var accountSummaryCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    $scope.open = function () {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Apps/generic/modal/Templates/AccountSummary.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            backdrop: false
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
};
```

Thanks

Comment: disable the button when you open the modal

Answer (score 14):

Use a boolean flag to avoid it:

```
var accountSummaryCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

    var opened = false;

    $scope.open = function () {

        if (opened) return;

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Apps/generic/modal/Templates/AccountSummary.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            backdrop: false
        });

        opened = true;

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
            $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            opened = false;
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            opened = false;
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works?  I see ```var opened = false;``` followed by ```if(opened) return;```  I don't see how this solves anything, even if you do have 2 upvotes on it.  Does the ```var opened = false``` belong outside the ```$scope.open``` function

Comment: You're right. `var opened = false;` was is the wrong place. I just corrected it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a simple directive which uses same technique as in J. Bruni's answer.

```
/**
 * Directive which helps to prevent multiple modals opened when clicking same button many times.
 *
 * Just replace "ng-click" with "open-single-modal" in your html. Example:
 *
 * <button open-single-modal="openModal()">Open Window</button>
 *
 * NOTICE! "openModal()" function must return modalInstance which is a result of "$uibModal.open()"
 */
app.directive('openSingleModal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var opened = false;

            element.bind('click', function () {
                if(opened) {
                    return;
                }

                opened = true;
                var modalInstance = scope.$eval(attrs.openSingleModal);

                if(!modalInstance || !modalInstance.result || typeof modalInstance.result.then !== 'function') {
                    console.error('Incorrect modal instance returned from the open modal function', element, modalInstance);
                    return;
                }

                modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                    opened = false;
                }, function () {
                    opened = false;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

To switch your code for this directive just change "ng-click" to "open-single-modal" and the function fired by ng-click must return modal instance.

Example. Before:

`<a ng-click="openModal()">Open Me!</a>`

After:

`<a open-single-modal="openModal()">Open Me!</a>`

and

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
    return $uibModal.open(...);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

J Bruni's answer is very good, but instead of using an additional variable, use what you already have with `modalInstance`. Since you declare modal instance higher up, you also gain flexibility to use that variable elsewhere (such as for when you may want to dismiss the dialog).

```
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var modalInstance;        /*assign to undefined if you like to be explicit*/

        element.bind('click', function () {
            if(modalInstance) {
                return;
            }

            modalInstance = scope.$eval(attrs.openSingleModal);

            if(!modalInstance || !modalInstance.result || typeof modalInstance.result.then !== 'function') {
                console.error('Incorrect modal instance returned from the open modal function', element, modalInstance);
                return;
            }

            modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                modalInstance = undefined;
            }, function () {
                modalInstance = undefined;
            });
        });
    }
```